# How to transform this link into jquery.load()?

Tags: jquery

I need to transform this `<a>` link into `jquery.load()` - how to do that?

This is the link:

```html
<a href="exibelinha.asp?linha=<%= rs_linhas("linha")%>" class="whatever">
    <img src="produtos/linhas/pequeno/<%= rs_linhas("foto_inicial")%>" alt="">
    <h3><%= rs_linhas("linha")%></h3>
</a>
```

I need to implement this with this jQuery script:

```
$('#exibe_galeria').click(function(e) {
    $('#galeria_oculta').show();
    $('#container').load('exibelinha.asp?xxxx'); //here i need to call the link
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Inside my load, I need to call another page (exibelinha.asp) with this strings `?linha=<%= rs_linhas("linha")%>`

Comment: jQuery works on HTML, please show the rendered HTML as seen by the browser (`view source`), *not* the ASP server-side script. And where, and what, is `#exibe_galeria`?

Comment: Does this not work? `$('#container').load('exibelinha.asp?linha=<%= rs_linhas("linha")%>');`

Comment: If it's something that you'd like to extract out of the URL portion, but still allow future reference by JavaScript, use the `data` attributes. e.g. `<a href="..." data-linha="<%= rs_linhas("linha") %>" ...></a>` (Then use `.data` to retrieve it)

Comment: Is the jquery script in the asp-file or in an external javascript file?

Comment: @DavidThomas `#exibegaleria` its only a simple DIV inside my page.. i use this to build custom lightbox, overing the page...  and i need to show my server-side script because i need to use them into my load page...

Comment: My point is that the server-side code is irrelevant to the jQuery and JavaScript; to work with client-side code we need to know what the client sees. And I'm not familiar with ASP, so I can't parse that in my head, unfortunately.

Comment: @Mario the libary its external, but my `document.ready` function its inside the asp-file...

Comment: @Preston then I would suggest bfavaretto's answer.

Comment: @DavidThomas ah.. sorry.. the client-side see this:

`<a href="exibelinha.asp?linha=Beach" class="whatever">
    <img src="produtos/linhas/pequeno/Beach_01.jpg>" alt="">
    <h3>BEACH</h3>
</a>`

is that u need?

and in the page `exibelinha.asp` i show the big image with their thumbs...

Comment: @Mario ok Mario, i will try...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just stop the default behavior of the link click event, then use the code you already have. You probably need an id or class on your anchor, to be able to create selector that won't affect other links on the page. Something like this:

**HTML**

```
<a id="link_exibelinha" href="exibelinha.asp?linha=<%= rs_linhas("linha")%>" class="whatever">
...
```

**JS**

```
$('#link_exibelinha').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = this.href;
    $('#galeria_oculta').show();
    $('#container').load(url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly then here is what you can try.

```
$('.whatever').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();//This will prevent the default behavior of the link
     $('#container').load(this.href);//This will get href from anchor and will load it
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.whatever').on('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#container').load(this.href);
});
```